# How to fetch specific columns in a row and transfer it to another table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to transfer a particular column only. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
 btnAdd.on('click', function () {

                        var trItem = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
                        trItem.find("input").remove();
                        trItem.add("<tr>").append("</tr>");

                        $("#products").append(trItem);

                        console.log(btnAdd);

})
```

thank you so much.

Comment: Try using $(this).closest("tr").remove(); instead, whats happening now? Please specify what isnt working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. It's getting the entire row. I just want 2 specific columns to show up.

Comment: So you want to append a new row to the second table, containing only one cell that is a copy of a particular cell in the source table's row?
 `.append("</tr>")` doesn't make sense. Remember that you're not manipulating an underlying string of HTML, you're manipulating the DOM, so trying to append a closing tag doesn't make sense.

Comment: can use `trItem.column("input:name")` ?

Comment: there are 3 cells in a row actually and i want to display the two columns.

by using trItem.column("input:name"), how can I enter another cell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify all cells need to be cloned.

Function "funcCloneRow" will clone a row (tr) and add cell's content by "tdKeyArr".
Remember that "tdKeyArr" is an array contain choosen cells's position, like this:

```js
$(function() {
 var funcCloneRow = function($table1, $table2, trIndex, tdKeyArr) {
  // define. If tdKeyArr == undefinded, all the cell in choosen tr will be cloned
  if($table1 == undefined || $table2 == undefined || trIndex == undefined) {
   return;
  }
  // clone row
  var $tr = $table1.find('tr').eq(trIndex).clone();
  // get cell content
  if(tdKeyArr != undefined) {
   $tr.children('td').text('');
   for (var i = 0; i < tdKeyArr.length; i++) {
    $tr.children('td').eq(tdKeyArr[i]).html($table1.find('tr').eq(trIndex).children('td').eq(tdKeyArr[i]).html());
   }
  }
  // append new row to second table
  if ($table2.children('tbody').length) {
   $table2.children('tbody').append($tr);
  }
  else {
   $table2.append($tr);
  }
 }
 $('table button').on('click', function(event) {
  funcCloneRow($('#table1'), $('#table2'), $(this).closest('tr').index(), [$(this).parent().index(), 1]);
 });
});
```

```css
table {
 float:left;
 margin-right:100px;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:top;
}
table th,
table td {
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <table id="table1">
  <tr>
   <th>head 1</th>
   <th>head 2</th>
   <th>head 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>row 1</td>
   <td>row 1</td>
   <td><button>Append</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>row 2</td>
   <td>row 2</td>
   <td><button>Append</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>row 3</td>
   <td>row 3</td>
   <td><button>Append</button></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <table id="table2">
  <tr>
   <th>head 1</th>
   <th>head 2</th>
   <th>head 3</th>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```